# Invalid indirection и не могу понять из-за чего

Tags: c++, c, borland

Сам код:

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>
include <conio.h>
include <conio.h>
include <string.h>

int printchar(char ch[30])
{
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
         if (ch[i]==' ') break;
         printf("%c",ch[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct student
{
    char name[30];
    int day;
    int mounth;
    int year;
    int rating;
}
std[20];
clrscr();
strcpy(std[0].name,"Alexey "; std[0].day=1; std[0].mounth=1; std[0].year=1994; std[0].rating=3;
strcpy(std[1].name,"Dmitriy "; std[1].day=7; std[1].mounth=11; std[1].year=1992; std[1].rating=5;
strcpy(std[2].name,"Petr "; std[2].day=14; std[2].mounth=8; std[3].year=1993; std[2].rating=3;
strcpy(std[3].name,"Alexsandr "; std[3].day=1; std[3].mounth=6; std[3].year=1993; std[3].rating=3;
strcpy(std[4].name,"Ivan "; std[4].day=11; std[4].mounth=12; std[4].year=1992; std[4].rating=3;
strcpy(std[5].name,"Anton "; std[5].day=5; std[5].mounth=12; std[5].year=1992; std[5].rating=4;
strcpy(std[6].name,"Daniil "; std[6].day=5; std[6].mounth=10; std[6].year=1995; std[0].rating=5;
for (i=0;i<7;i++)
if (std[1].rating[0]=='5')            // тут ошибка, не пойму из-за чего
{
    printchar(std[i].name);
    printf (" "); printf ("%d",std[i].day); printf ("."); printf ("%d",std[i].mount); printf ("."); printf ("%d",std[i].year); printf ("%d",std[i].rating);
    printf ("\n");
}
getch();
}
```

Ах да, программа должна вывести на экран студентов отличников

Answer (score 4):

У вас `std[1].rating` - поле типа `int`, а вы пытаетесь обратиться к нему как к массиву. Отсюда ошибка. И, скорее всего, вы имели ввиду `std[i].rating`, а не `std[1].rating`.

**UPD**

Ещё одна проблема - вы пытаетесь сравнивать `int` и `char`. В такой ситуации компилятор приводит `char` к `int` подставляя вместо него ASCII-код символа (для `'5'` ASCII-код равен 53), поэтому вы фактически ищете студентов с оценкой 53. Уберите кавычки, и должно заработать.

Comment: Конечно, std[i].rating, описался.
Я исправил эту строку, как

if (std[i].rating=='5')

Однако в итоге программа запускается, но ничего не выводит

Comment: И правда) Спасибо большое)